# How to enable Javascript in Druid

Tags: druid

I have been using Druid for the past week and wanted to enable javascript for some postAggregations.

I think I followed the outlined steps and updated the `common.runtime.properties` file in `../con f/druid/_common/` to include `druid.javascript.enabled=true`. I then stopped the current processes and re-ran the Quickstart procedures, but it still says that JavaScript is disabled:

```
{
  "error" : "Unknown exception",
  "errorMessage" : "Instantiation of [simple type, class io.druid.query.aggregation.post.JavaScriptPostAggregator] value failed: JavaScript is disabled. (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0])",
  "errorClass" : "com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException",
  "host" : null
}
```

I am currently running it in the 'Quickstart' configuration - single local machine. Any pointers? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript Query For druid Aggregation. Save the file as .body and hit the curl request.
This is a sample query for Average value.

> curl -X POST "http://localhost:8082/druid/v2/?pretty" \ -H
>   'content-type: application/json' -d @query.body

```
{
   "queryType":"groupBy",
   "dataSource":"whirldata",
   "granularity":"all",
   "dimensions":[],
   "aggregations":[{"name":"rows","type":"count","fieldName":"rows"},
{"name":"TargetDOS","type":"doubleSum","fieldName":"Target DOS"}],"postAggregations":[
{
  "type": "javascript",
  "name": "Target DOS Average",
  "fieldNames": ["TargetDOS", "rows"],
  "function": "function(TargetDOS, rows) { return Math.abs(TargetDOS) / rows; }"
}],   "intervals":[ "2006-01-01T00:00:00.000Z/2020-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"  ]}
```

Comment: first you need to enabled the java script in all common.runtime.properties file to include druid.javascript.enabled=true

Answer (score -1):

The part you are missing is likely that the quickstart reads configs from `conf-quickstart` rather than `conf`. So try editing `conf-quickstart/druid/_common/common.runtime.properties`.